# Hover only works in one point in plotly's Scatter3D

Tags: javascript, python, plotly, data-visualization

I'm trying to visualize the a variable depending on 3 more variables (test score of a ML algorithm depending on 3 hyperparameters), thus I created a 3D scatter plot. It's working well, but hover only works on one of the 100 points and I don't know why. No matter where I hover, the only info displayed is that of that that point.

I tried setting hovermode='closest' and some other stuff but nothing worked so far. How can I made hover work for all of the points?

You can see my plot [here](https://plot.ly/~xoelop/124/#plot):

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

I was setting `opacity=1` and apparently you can't do that with 3D scatter plots when you set the `line` property.

```
trace = go.Scatter3d(
x=df4['param_max_features'],
y=df4['param_n_estimators'],
z=df4['mean_test_score'],
text=text,
mode='markers', 
marker=dict(
    size=df4.mean_fit_time * 4,
    sizemode='area',
    color=df4.mean_test_score,
    opacity=0.99,
    colorscale='Viridis',
    colorbar=dict(title = 'Test score'),
    line=dict(color='rgb(140, 140, 170)')
),
```

)

if you set `opacity` to any number lower than 1 it works.

Cheers!